# Given three positive numbers $a,\,b,\,c$ . Prove that $(\!abc+ a+ b+ c\!)^{3}\geqq 8\,abc(\!1+ a\!)(\!1+ b\!)(\!1+ c\!)$ .

Tags: inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method, uvw

Given three positive numbers $a,\,b,\,c$ . Prove that $$(\!abc+ a+ b+ c\!)^{3}\geqslant 8\,abc(\!1+ a\!)(\!1+ b\!)(\!1+ c\!).$$

*My own problem is given a solution, and I'm looking forward to seeing a nicer one(s), thank you !*

*Solution.* Without loss of generality, we can suppose $(a- 1)(b- 1)\geqslant 0 \rightarrow 1+ ab\geqslant a+ b$. Then

\begin{align*} (abc+ a+ b+ c)^{3}&= \left ( c(1+ ab)+ a+ b \right )^{2}\left ( c(1+ ab)+ a+ b \right )\\& \geqslant 4\,c(1+ ab)(a+ b)\left ( c(a+ b)+ (a+ b) \right )\\&= 2c(a+ b)^{2}(2+ 2ab)(1+ c)\\& \end{align*}

Again, by using a.m.-g.m.-inequality, we have $$2c\left(a+ b\right)^{2}\left( 2+ 2ab\right)\left( 1+ c\right)\geqslant 8abc\left(1+ a\right)\left(1+ b\right)\left(1+ c\right)$$

That is *q.e.d*!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After replacing $a\rightarrow\frac{1}{a},$ $b\rightarrow\frac{1}{b}$ and $c\rightarrow\frac{1}{c}$ we need to prove that
$$(1+ab+ac+bc)^3\geq8abc(1+a)(1+b)(1+c).$$
Now, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2,$ where $v>0$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$(1+3v^2)^3\geq8w^3(1+w^3+3v^2+3u)$$ or
$$(1+3v^2)\geq8(w^3+w^6+3v^3w^2+3uw^3)$$ and since by AM-GM $v\geq w$ and $v^4\geq uw^3,$ it's enough to prove that:
$$(1+3v^2)^3\geq8(v^3+v^6+3v^5+3v^4)$$ or
$$(1+3v^2)^3\geq8v^3(1+v)^3$$ or
$$1+3v^2\geq2v(1+v)$$ or
$$(1-v)^2\geq0$$ and we are done!

Also, $uvw$ kills this inequality, but it's not so nice.

Comment: YOU'RE SO SUPER ! What makes you think to replace by a substitution?

Comment: I think your solution is the neatest and the best one !

Comment: @HanhVyheaven28 Because after this substitution the inequality looks simpler.Thank you!

Comment: Wow, that's so impressive! I found it by discriminant and you do this easily!

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** By AM-GM,
$$(abc+a) + (b+c) \geqslant 2a\sqrt{bc}+2\sqrt{bc} = 2\sqrt{bc}(1+a)$$

Now multiply three such inequalities (after cyclical shift).

Comment: Very nice! Bravo! +1

Comment: 'Now multiply three such inequalities (after cyclical shift).', that made a big impres !